# Octoparse and relative Xpath iframe extraction issues

Tags: xpath, iframe

I am trying to use Octoparse to extract the podcast details from Marie Brown's "Beyond the kitchen table" website. https://beyondthekitchentable.co.uk/podcast/

I'm using Octoparse's free version which allows for scraping locally. The problem is that while Octoparse will automatically auto-detect the Title, Title_URL, and Content webpage data and correctly set up the Pagination, Scroll Page, and Loop item workflow to extract (Title, Title_URL, and Content fields), it does not auto-detect the 'Date' and 'Podcast time duration' fields of each individual podcast as these pieces appear to be getting embedded from an iframe. However, while I am able to custom add Date and Podcast time duration using an Absolute Xpath i.e. `//div[@class="cfm-episodes-list"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/iframe[1]`. This results in the same value copied for each record. So when I attempt to fix this by using the Relative XPath setting in Octoparse to loop each item `//span[@class="cp-episode-date"]` in order to gather all individually unique, it does not get any values even though this relative Xpath `//span[@class="cp-episode-date"]` is finding all items when I use WebDevTools to search and find all occurrences seen within Chrome. I saw what might be another helpful post on Stackexchange about this but I was not able to make sense of it.

This portion `//span[@class="cp-episode-date"]` is relative Xpath as it finds multiple Date items in Chrome WebDevTools but it is not complete and I am not sure how to implement the unique Iframe traversal for the Date and Podcast time duration custom added fields I added that Octoparse's Relative XPath settings are looking for. I even tried to install the SelectorsHub Chrome browser extension but it didn't pull up the nested SelectorHub to query the Xpath the way the SelectorHub Youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srExpm-d9dU) demonstrates - it only showed me the relative Xpath I already am showing below.

Please have a look at this site using Octoparse and see if it is possible. If so, how can I do it?

**When Absolute Path is used -** `//div[@class="cfm-episodes-list"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/iframe[1]`
[image]

[image]

vs.

**When Relative Path is used -** `//span[@class="cp-episode-date"]`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of iframes inside the webpage. I don't know if Octoparse could handle this. Choose another starting point.

For example, use Apple Podcast :

https://podcasts.apple.com/gb/podcast/the-website-coach/id1587503231

Dates could be recovered with the following XPath :

```
//div[@class="l-row"]//time[@class]/@aria-label
```

Other possibility, scrape the following page :

https://feeds.captivate.fm/the-website-coach/

Dates could be recovered with the following XPath :

```
//h4/text()
```

Even easier, get directly the data from this URL (.json file) :

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1587503231&media=podcast&entity=podcastEpisode&limit=100

Answer (score 0):

Try customize field to match with data type of the field. The reason for blank field may be the data type of the field may be set as url or other data type. Go to vertical view>more>customize field, then set it back to text.